# Pls why am I getting this error when I run a test in hardhat?

Tags: solidity, ether, hardhat

Whenever I run the test command, I keep getting this error:

```
  0 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) Crud uint test
       Initial form must be empty:
     ReferenceError: createForm is not defined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\uint\Crud.test.js:18:12)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\uint\Crud.test.js:18:5)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

------------This is what my code looks like---------------

Here is my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Crud {
    uint256 private age;
    string public name = "";
    // address creator;

    // constructor(address) {
    //     creator = msg.sender;
    // }

    function createForm(
        uint256 _age,
        string memory _name
        // address
    ) public {
        age = _age;
        name = _name;
        // creator = msg.sender;
    }

    function deleteForm() public {
        delete age;
        delete name;
    }

    function getForm()
        public
        view
        returns (
            uint256,
            string memory /*,
            address*/
        )
    {
        return (age, name /*, creator*/);
    }
}
```

Here is my test file.

```
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { network, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Crud uint test", () => {
  let crud, deployer;
  const name = "";
  const age = 0;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
    const Crud = await ethers.getContractFactory("Crud");
    crud = await Crud.deploy();
    await crud.deployed();
  });

  it("Initial form must be empty", async () => {
    await crud.createForm(age, name);
    assert(crud.createForm.name, name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

First, you are using `assert` incorrectly. The first argument to `assert` is the assertion itself and must evaluate to `true` or `false`, where the second parameter is an optional failure message.

Second, you are asserting on `crud.createForm.name` which does not exist; `crud.createForm` is a function.

Going by your contract, the solution would be to replace your `assert` line with:

```js
const form = await crud.getForm();
assert(form[0] === age, "age does not match");
assert(form[1] === name, "name does not match");
```

Note that you cannot use `form.name` and `form.age` because the return values are unnamed in your contract.

Comment: I did that already and I try it again just now, I still get same error. ` Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=0, expectedCount=2, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)`

Comment: Are you sure? You are calling `crud.createForm` twice, once with arguments and once without. I assume the second line (where you assign the return value) is supposed to be `crud.getForm`?

Comment: Can you pls edit your answer and explain how I can make the test work. I'm getting another error: AssertionError: Unspecified AssertionError

Comment: Could you edit your question first and explain more about that error? That is a new error not included in the original question, so I need context (e.g. a line). Also, please update the test to reflect what you have changed it to.

Comment: Okay, Ive update the question

Comment: Updated my answer as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138123/discussion-between-onbjerg-and-paulliano).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I replaced this in your second line answer: assert(form[0].toString() === age.toString(), "age does not match"); and it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `constructor` to not accept any argument. The way you are assigning the `creator` value doesn't need and argument. `msg.sender` value is always available, so you don't need to pass it. So your constructor can look like this:

```
    constructor() {
        creator = msg.sender;
    }
```

This modification should allow you to correctly deploy the smart contract, as for the test cases, in the first line you are already creating one form. The assertion actually creates a `Promise` object, so it won't have any effect on the smart contract until it is sent. You can modify the statements like this:

```
    await crud.createForm(age, name);
    const result = await crud.getForm()
    assert(result[1] === name, 'name mismatch');
```

This way, you are setting the values in the first line, getting them in the second and comparing them in the third.